# Do I need to renew my passport now?

Tags: passports

I am traveling to Greece, Italy, and other European Union countries in March.  My passport expires in June. Do I need to renew my passport before I go?  I'd prefer to renew it only when I need to.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  When are you planning on leaving EU? What countries passport do you hold?  And why would you prefer not to renew your passport and not worry about it?

Comment: Not all EU members are part of the Schengen area (e.g. UK), and not all members of the Schengen area are part of the EU (e.g. Norway), so whatever additional detail you can provide will be helpful. And as Karlson noted, the answer will depend on your nationality (i.e. which passport you will use to enter and exit).

Comment: EU is really Schengen, Romania and Bulgaria (which should already follow the same rules for the most part), Croatia, UK and Ireland. It should not be too difficult to give a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 8):

Passport requirements vary from country to country, and whilst all countries in the Schengen Zone of the European Union have synchronized rules, these do not apply to all 'other European Union countries' as you've listed.

Specifically for Schengen countries, as of July last year there is a requirement for your passport to have at least 3 months expiry beyond the END of your travels within the Schengen zone.  3 months is defined as the same day that you will leave, 3 months later.

As you've only listed the months it's not possible to tell if you will have 3 months spare at the end, but at best you're cutting it very fine. If your passport expires June 15, then you will need to have plans to leave no later than the 15th of March.

Some other European countries require 6 months validity, whilst others such as the UK normally require zero.

Personally I would strongly suggest getting your passport renewed.